# ItemView won't render

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I am using Backbone, Marionette and RequireJS to make an application, but I have trouble with Marionette's ItemView. I am trying to render a template, but an error is always thrown.

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
var Marionette = require('marionette'),
    Backbone = require('backbone');

var loadModule = Marionette.Module.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('Load module');
    }
});

var template = '<div><%= message %></div>'
var ItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({    
    region: '#main',
    template: template,
    model: {message: 'test'}
});

var view = new ItemView();
view.render();

return loadModule;
});
```

And my html file contains a div with id main. When I run the code above I get the error:
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined' when view.render() is called.

Any suggestions would help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing a model to your view on instantiation. When Marionette tries to render, it expects to pass data from the model to the template function (in this case underscores _.template()). Since your template is referencing some data:

```
var template = '<div><%= message %></div>'
```

in this case "message", it won't be able to interpolate the value. Generally speaking what you would do on instantiation would look something like this:

```
var myModel = new MyModel();

var view = new ItemView({ model: myModel });
```

Comment: What you suggested removed the error but the template is still not added to the DOM. Here are my improvements:  `var Message = Backbone.Model.extend(); 
    var message = new Message({
        title: "Title",
        description: "Description"
    });

    template = '<div><%= message.title %> This is a test</div>'
    var ItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({    
     region: '#main',
     template: template,
     model: message
    });

    var view = new ItemView();
    view.render();`

Comment: the variable 'message' is your model instance, not the data itself that it contains, so just reference the attributes directly in your template: <%= title %> Also, if you could add all the relevant code to a jsbin or jsfiddle it would be helpful

Comment: Ok. I tried removing the model and only make the ItemView render a template with only text. Like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/my0vy9wm/). This is still not working.

Comment: Unless you're either A. specifying a selector for your view's el or B. going to show this div in an existing region, calling render won't do anything. Marionette needs to know where to append the markup generated for this view. Is there more code that you haven't included in that jsfiddle?

Comment: I was missing the selector inside el tag, so now it's working. The changes I made was [link](http://jsfiddle.net/my0vy9wm/2/). Thanks a lot for the help!